# Python Calculation Using List

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

How can I perform calculations in python using two lists? Where the first calculation would be, c = -(1)/cos(4), second being, c = -(5)/cos(6), etc

```
import numpy as np
x, y = [1,5,2,1], [4,6,2,3]

c = []
c = -x/(np.cos(y))
print(c)
```

When I try this I currently get the error :

```
TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'
```

Comment: why are you trying to use lists like numpy arrays?

Comment: To me, it's not clear what you're asking. Do you want to use `list` like a numpy-array? (if so, why avoid numpy?) Or do you want to learn how to use numpy arrays?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done without numpy:

```
from math import cos
x, y = [1,5,2,1], [4,6,2,3]
c = [-i/cos(j) for i,j in zip(x,y)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the list to numpy array.

```py
c = -np.array(x)/(np.cos(y))
print(c)
```

now you will have the results store in the np array

```py
array([ 1.52988566, -5.20740963,  4.80599592,  1.01010867])
```

or if you want a list again

```
c = list(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the length of the list:

```
import numpy as np
x, y = [1,5,2,1], [4,6,2,3]

c = []
for i in range(0, len(x)):
    f = -x[i]/(np.cos(y[i]))
    c.append(f)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope ... there is no specific reason ... to handle as a list.

```
import numpy as np
x, y = [1,5,2,1],[4,6,2,3]
c = []
for k in range (len(x)):
    c = -x[k]/(np.cos(y[k]))
    print(c)

Result:
1.5298856564663974
-5.207409632975539
4.805995923444762
1.0101086659079939
```

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the problem: `TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'`

So you could just negate elsewhere (where you have a NumPy array):

```
c = -x/np.cos(y)     # Error
c = x/-np.cos(y)     # [ 1.52988566 -5.20740963  4.80599592  1.01010867]
c = -(x/np.cos(y))   # [ 1.52988566 -5.20740963  4.80599592  1.01010867]
```